# How do I execute multiple requests for each iteration for external JSON file?

Tags: javascript, postman

I am creating a pre-request scirpt in Postman

I have the following data file in JSON:

```
[
  {
    "sequence": "CheckCompany",
    "company": ["Google", "Microsoft"]
  },
  {
    "sequence": "CheckFunction",
    "function": ["Func1", "Func2"]
  }
]
```

Currently, there are 2 iterations.
For each iteration, where the is an array of values like company and function this should execute a request to call that same API to process items within the array.

Iteration 1: First API call → execute API with company = Google

Iteration 1: Second API call → execute API with company = Microsoft

Iteration 2: Third API call → execute API with function = func1

Iteration 2: Fourth API call → execute API with function = func2

How do I achieve this using JScript ?
Normally Postman will iterate for each item in the array but I have an array within a JSON element.
How does iteration work fin this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approaches

```
const data = [
    {
        "sequence": "CheckCompany",
        "company": ["Google", "Microsoft"]
    },
    {
        "sequence": "CheckFunction",
        "function": ["Func1", "Func2"]
    }
]

const  find_item = (searchSequence, searchItem) => {
    if (searchSequence == 'CheckCompany') {
        return data.find(item => item.sequence == searchSequence)
            .company.find(item => {
                return item == searchItem;
            })
    } else {
        return data.find(item => item.sequence == searchSequence)
            .function.find(item => {
                return item == searchItem;
            })
    }
}

console.log(find_item('CheckCompany', 'Microsoft'))
console.log(find_item('CheckCompany', 'Google'))
console.log(find_item('CheckFunction', 'Func1'))
console.log(find_item('CheckFunction', 'Func2'))
```

run it

```
$ node filter.js
Microsoft
Google
Func1
Func2
```